# subgroups of p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$. I already shown that it has $p^2+p+1$ subgroups of order $p$. I have this conjecture that is has  $p+1$ subgroups of order $p^2$. Any hints on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Given that what you have shown does not hold for an arbitrary non-abelian group of order $p^3$, it might have been good to include whatever extra conditions were put on the group, as it might have been relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ and let $Z$ be the center of $G$. Then
$|Z| = p$ since $Z\neq 1$ and $G/Z$ is not cyclic. Since $G/Z$ has order $p^2$, it is abelian, so $Z = [G,G]$. Since $G/Z \cong C_p × C_p$, there are exactly $p + 1$ subgroups $A$ of $G$ with $|A|=p^2$.

References:

[Non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186243/non-abelian-group-g-of-order-p3)

Comment: How do u knw there is exactly $p+1$ subgroups of order $p^2$?