# If $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^{3}$ for prime p , then the center of $G$ is generated by all elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

If $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^{3}$ for prime p , then the center of $G$ is generated by all elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}(a,b\in G).$

i.e. $C(G)=G',$where $C(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $G'$ is the comutator subgroup of $G$

Here is my attempt :

Note that the center $C(G)$ is of order $p:$

As $G$ is a $p-$group, then $C(G)$ is non-trivial and $C(G)\unlhd G,$

so, $|C(G)|=$$p$ or $p^2$ or $p^3$

Case(i):

$|C(G)|=p^{3}$, then $C(G)=G$ forces that $G$ is abelian, a contradiction.

Case(ii):

$|C(G)|=p^{2},$ then the order of the quotient group $G/C(G)$ is $p$. So,the original  $G$ must be abelian, $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$a contradiction.

Therefore, consider this quotient group $G/C(G)\,,$ again.

Now the order of $\,G/C(G)$ is $p^{2}$ which implies that $G/C(G)$ is abelian.
Then $C(G)$ must contains the comutator of $G$,that is, $G'$. Therefore $G'\le C(G)$ and $|C(G)|=p$, so either $G'=\langle e\rangle$ or $G'=C(G)$. But $G'=\langle e \rangle$ gives that G is abelian, which is impossible.

Whence , the only possibility is that $G'=C(G),$so our conclusion follows.

If you have the time , please check my proof for validity . Any suggestion and advice will be better for me . Thanks a lot and considering my request.

Comment: It looks fine to me. A little too wordy, but fine.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2561409)

Comment: You can directly compare your answer with the answer by hamid kamali from the duplicate. It makes it easy to see how you can shorten it.